# What is a good alternative to Zoho Reports?

Tags: cloud-service, data-analysis, microsoft-excel, reporting, spreadsheet

What other services are similar to Zoho Reports? I performed a search for alternatives and all articles seemed to focus on the CRM and so it was a false comparison. Al the alternatives were about CRM solutions, not reports.

I'm interested in the reports aspect of Zoho... import some data (like a spreadsheet) and then make some nice reports out of it. Preferably in the cloud, but if there are some great Windows Applications for this also then I wouldn't mind hearing about those as well. As far as cloud services go, I'm looking for one with at least a limited Free option... e.g you can make a certain # of reports or something.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recs. Including the required/desired features is much better than similar to x; more people will know software that <feature list> than will likely know specific software and comparables.

Comment: Any reporting software could fit your description, even Google Spreadsheet. Please tell us more: how many data rows, what kind of reports/graphs, do you need OLAP cubes, do you need automatic scheduled generation?

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, you want a reporting software that can handle Excel files directly, if that's the case, then i recommend you to try [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com), which can use Excel files as if they were any database and make standard SQL queries against them with a simple drag and drop interface.

Just notice that DBxtra it's not cloud based so it's meant to be installed in your own server or hosting provider.

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist.